# Log4j2 RollingFile: Use todays date in current logfile (refreshing fileName)

Tags: java, log4j2

I had a webservice using log4j, and upgraded it to use log4j2 so I could take advantage of the way log4j2 can delete old log dated log files for you while log4j can't.

The logs are stored in the pattern */my_log_root/yyyyMMdd/myservice.log*. The relevant log4j.properties config looked like this:

```
log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/my_log_root/%d{yyyyMMdd}/myservice.log
```

This worked well, except old log files were never deleted. Now in log4j2 the properties file looks like this:

```
property.basePath = /my_log_root/

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName= ${basePath}/${date:yyyyMMdd}/myservice.log
appender.rolling.filePattern= ${basePath}/%d{yyyyMMdd}/myservice.log

appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.basePath = ${basePath}
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 3
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 30d
```

With this properties file, the old log files are deleted (the empty directories remain, but that's not too bad).

The only problem is with the current days log. It appears as if log4j2 is never refreshing the fileName once it's calculated. For example, when I relaunched the service on 2019-06-21, it wrote the file correctly to */my_log_root/20190621/myservice.log*. However, now a few days later, it's still writing the current log to  */my_log_root/20190621/myservice.log*. At the end of the day it will rotate the log to the appropriate dated directory, and then start writing the new log to the 21st.

Is it possible to make log4j2 refresh it's current logs location each day or does it not support this?